# how can i type special caharacters in vi editor

Tags: linux, editor

now i cant login in a pc. i am using linux ubuntu. now i want change some settings for that i want to type semicolon but it is not coming..is there any format to type in vi editor..some body know means tell me how can type in vi editor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>i</kbd> first, to enter to insert mode (when you open vi, you are in command mode by default).

Then, do your editing.

When you are done, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then type `:wq` and enter to save your changes.

Also note that `vi` is an advanced editor; if you just want to make some quick changes, an easier one, like `nano`, might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to type a semi-colon if you're in insert mode.  By default in vi you are in command mode, and to go to insert mode you have to use a keystroke like 'i' (insert), 'o' (begin editing on the next line), etc.